# Java App Close Unexpectedly

Tags: java

**i m not the developer but user of one of Java App which was running flawlessly and suddenly started creating problems. and its working fine on my another PC
here is the error log

please help me**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006e083a17, pid=1344, tid=0x0000000000000e90
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x513a17]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000588f2000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3728, stack(0x0000000058d20000,0x0000000058e20000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000001e66bdf30

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000059291ef0, RBX=0x000000000000000f, RCX=0x000000006350b010, RDX=0x0000000000000a08
RSP=0x0000000058e1c140, RBP=0x0000000058e1c240, RSI=0x000000000000000b, RDI=0x000000006350b070
R8 =0x0000000000000003, R9 =0x000000005abf77b0, R10=0x0000000000000003, R11=0x0000000000000010
R12=0x000000006350b080, R13=0x0000000000000004, R14=0x0000000058e1c830, R15=0x000000005abf7758
RIP=0x000000006e083a17, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000058e1c140)
0x0000000058e1c140:   000000006e34eca0 0000000000000005
0x0000000058e1c150:   0000000000000005 0000000058e1c240
0x0000000058e1c160:   0000000000000a87 0000000063960160
0x0000000058e1c170:   000000006395ac60 0000000058e1c400
0x0000000058e1c180:   0000000000000001 0000000000000000
0x0000000058e1c190:   000000000000000b 000000006350b070
0x0000000058e1c1a0:   0000000000000003 0000000000000003
0x0000000058e1c1b0:   0000000000000000 0000000300000004
0x0000000058e1c1c0:   00000a4000000000 0000000058e1c510
0x0000000058e1c1d0:   000000000000000f 000000005c6a2f90
0x0000000058e1c1e0:   000000005abf77b0 00000a4000000004
0x0000000058e1c1f0:   0000000058e1c510 000000000000000f
0x0000000058e1c200:   000000005c6a0690 0000000000000965
0x0000000058e1c210:   000000005b4e4040 000000005c48ced0
0x0000000058e1c220:   ffffffffa1aca690 00000000000003d8
0x0000000058e1c230:   000000005c48d2a8 000000005c48cec0 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006e083a17)
0x000000006e0839f7:   8b fe 4c 8b b5 80 02 00 00 49 63 4f 28 45 8b 4f
0x000000006e083a07:   18 49 8b 86 28 01 00 00 4c 89 7d 18 44 89 4d a0
0x000000006e083a17:   44 8b 04 88 41 0f b6 47 2c 24 0f 44 89 45 00 3c
0x000000006e083a27:   0c 0f 85 b3 00 00 00 45 3b 86 e8 00 00 00 0f 83 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000059291ef0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000006350b010 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000a08 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000058e1c140 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000588f2000
RBP=0x0000000058e1c240 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000588f2000
RSI=0x000000000000000b is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000006350b070 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000005abf77b0 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000006350b080 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000058e1c830 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000588f2000
R15=0x000000005abf7758 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000058d20000,0x0000000058e20000],  sp=0x0000000058e1c140,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x513a17]
V  [jvm.dll+0x468672]
V  [jvm.dll+0x473aab]
V  [jvm.dll+0x476378]
V  [jvm.dll+0x458d82]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa57c2]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa60ff]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2451a4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x29c18a]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21d9f]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x21e3b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1f56d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x33281]


Current CompileTask:
C2:  29532 5880   !   4       sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource::doFetch (253 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000005c90a800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=6300, stack(0x000000005f150000,0x000000005f250000)]
  0x000000005c909800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5488, stack(0x0000000067420000,0x0000000067520000)]
  0x000000005c909000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:03:59:a2" [_thread_blocked, id=1228, stack(0x0000000064e70000,0x0000000064f70000)]
  0x000000005c908000 JavaThread "Timer-29" [_thread_blocked, id=1312, stack(0x0000000067a30000,0x0000000067b30000)]
  0x000000005c907800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5692, stack(0x00000000677c0000,0x00000000678c0000)]
  0x000000005c906800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:5e:82:5c" [_thread_blocked, id=6396, stack(0x0000000067030000,0x0000000067130000)]
  0x000000005c906000 JavaThread "Timer-28" [_thread_blocked, id=3252, stack(0x00000000676a0000,0x00000000677a0000)]
  0x00000000596e6800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1920, stack(0x0000000067540000,0x0000000067640000)]
  0x00000000596e5800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:7f:f4:46" [_thread_blocked, id=5608, stack(0x0000000065270000,0x0000000065370000)]
  0x00000000596e5000 JavaThread "Timer-27" [_thread_blocked, id=5068, stack(0x0000000067320000,0x0000000067420000)]
  0x00000000596e4000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=4928, stack(0x0000000067180000,0x0000000067280000)]
  0x00000000596e3800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:d7:d8:05" [_thread_blocked, id=5708, stack(0x00000000665a0000,0x00000000666a0000)]
  0x00000000596e2800 JavaThread "Timer-26" [_thread_blocked, id=5296, stack(0x0000000066c60000,0x0000000066d60000)]
  0x00000000596e2000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=6724, stack(0x0000000066ef0000,0x0000000066ff0000)]
  0x00000000596e1000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:34:01:09" [_thread_blocked, id=3800, stack(0x0000000066d80000,0x0000000066e80000)]
  0x00000000596e0800 JavaThread "Timer-25" [_thread_blocked, id=2868, stack(0x00000000666c0000,0x00000000667c0000)]
  0x00000000596df800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1036, stack(0x0000000066b20000,0x0000000066c20000)]
  0x000000005bab3800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:cb:cc:1f" [_thread_blocked, id=5596, stack(0x0000000066480000,0x0000000066580000)]
  0x000000005bab2800 JavaThread "Timer-24" [_thread_blocked, id=6672, stack(0x0000000066380000,0x0000000066480000)]
  0x000000005bab2000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:51:57:4e" [_thread_blocked, id=7060, stack(0x0000000066a00000,0x0000000066b00000)]
  0x000000005bab1000 JavaThread "Timer-23" [_thread_blocked, id=5356, stack(0x00000000668f0000,0x00000000669f0000)]
  0x000000005bab0800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=3888, stack(0x00000000667e0000,0x00000000668e0000)]
  0x000000005baaf800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=2676, stack(0x00000000661e0000,0x00000000662e0000)]
  0x000000005baaf000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:e9:eb:1f" [_thread_blocked, id=1868, stack(0x0000000065ef0000,0x0000000065ff0000)]
  0x000000005baae000 JavaThread "Timer-22" [_thread_blocked, id=4092, stack(0x0000000066040000,0x0000000066140000)]
  0x000000005baad800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=6508, stack(0x0000000065de0000,0x0000000065ee0000)]
  0x000000005baac800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:30:09:c3" [_thread_blocked, id=4604, stack(0x0000000065cb0000,0x0000000065db0000)]
  0x000000005c4cd800 JavaThread "Timer-21" [_thread_blocked, id=2996, stack(0x0000000065b20000,0x0000000065c20000)]
  0x000000005c4cd000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=3228, stack(0x0000000065490000,0x0000000065590000)]
  0x000000005c4cc000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:15:39:81" [_thread_blocked, id=6212, stack(0x0000000065830000,0x0000000065930000)]
  0x000000005c4cb800 JavaThread "Timer-20" [_thread_blocked, id=764, stack(0x0000000065970000,0x0000000065a70000)]
  0x000000005c4ca800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5736, stack(0x00000000656d0000,0x00000000657d0000)]
  0x000000005c4ca000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:3c:5f:7c" [_thread_blocked, id=884, stack(0x0000000065070000,0x0000000065170000)]
  0x000000005c4c9000 JavaThread "Timer-19" [_thread_blocked, id=1028, stack(0x0000000065590000,0x0000000065690000)]
  0x000000005c4c8800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1304, stack(0x0000000065390000,0x0000000065490000)]
  0x000000005c4c7800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:2a:1b:41" [_thread_blocked, id=2016, stack(0x0000000064b60000,0x0000000064c60000)]
  0x000000005c4c7000 JavaThread "Timer-18" [_thread_blocked, id=5804, stack(0x0000000065170000,0x0000000065270000)]
  0x0000000063328800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5096, stack(0x0000000064f70000,0x0000000065070000)]
  0x0000000063327800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:22:fc:4d" [_thread_blocked, id=1624, stack(0x0000000064850000,0x0000000064950000)]
  0x0000000063327000 JavaThread "Timer-17" [_thread_blocked, id=6268, stack(0x00000000649c0000,0x0000000064ac0000)]
  0x0000000063326000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=2832, stack(0x0000000064630000,0x0000000064730000)]
  0x0000000063325800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:fb:77:23" [_thread_blocked, id=3272, stack(0x0000000064d70000,0x0000000064e70000)]
  0x0000000063324800 JavaThread "Timer-16" [_thread_blocked, id=6904, stack(0x0000000064c70000,0x0000000064d70000)]
  0x0000000063324000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1032, stack(0x0000000064740000,0x0000000064840000)]
  0x0000000063323000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:2b:65:1e" [_thread_blocked, id=1456, stack(0x0000000062d40000,0x0000000062e40000)]
  0x0000000063322800 JavaThread "Timer-15" [_thread_blocked, id=1740, stack(0x00000000644e0000,0x00000000645e0000)]
  0x0000000063321800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:c3:ec:a4" [_thread_blocked, id=6112, stack(0x0000000064300000,0x0000000064400000)]
  0x000000005c107800 JavaThread "Timer-14" [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x00000000641e0000,0x00000000642e0000)]
  0x000000005c106800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1264, stack(0x0000000063ff0000,0x00000000640f0000)]
  0x000000005c106000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=3960, stack(0x0000000062800000,0x0000000062900000)]
  0x000000005c105000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:a5:10:57" [_thread_blocked, id=6344, stack(0x0000000062e60000,0x0000000062f60000)]
  0x000000005c104800 JavaThread "Timer-13" [_thread_blocked, id=4916, stack(0x000000005fe50000,0x000000005ff50000)]
  0x000000005c103800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:12:ec:6b" [_thread_blocked, id=6920, stack(0x0000000062c00000,0x0000000062d00000)]
  0x000000005c103000 JavaThread "Timer-12" [_thread_blocked, id=224, stack(0x0000000062ae0000,0x0000000062be0000)]
  0x000000005c102000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5336, stack(0x0000000062930000,0x0000000062a30000)]
  0x000000005c101800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=812, stack(0x00000000626b0000,0x00000000627b0000)]
  0x000000005c100800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:1c:7d:0b" [_thread_in_Java, id=5048, stack(0x0000000062570000,0x0000000062670000)]
  0x000000005b001800 JavaThread "Timer-11" [_thread_blocked, id=4052, stack(0x0000000062390000,0x0000000062490000)]
  0x000000005b001000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=4376, stack(0x0000000061fd0000,0x00000000620d0000)]
  0x000000005b000000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:2d:cc:12" [_thread_blocked, id=6320, stack(0x0000000061ec0000,0x0000000061fc0000)]
  0x000000005afff800 JavaThread "Timer-10" [_thread_blocked, id=6956, stack(0x00000000611e0000,0x00000000612e0000)]
  0x000000005affe800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:5f:c9:da" [_thread_blocked, id=6556, stack(0x0000000061d00000,0x0000000061e00000)]
  0x000000005affe000 JavaThread "Timer-9" [_thread_blocked, id=1452, stack(0x0000000061b10000,0x0000000061c10000)]
  0x000000005affd000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5704, stack(0x0000000060e20000,0x0000000060f20000)]
  0x000000005affc800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:2f:2a:b6" [_thread_blocked, id=6172, stack(0x00000000619e0000,0x0000000061ae0000)]
  0x000000005affb800 JavaThread "Timer-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5396, stack(0x00000000618a0000,0x00000000619a0000)]
  0x000000005affb000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5696, stack(0x0000000061780000,0x0000000061880000)]
  0x000000005b870000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=704, stack(0x0000000061660000,0x0000000061760000)]
  0x000000005b86f000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:20:69:1a" [_thread_blocked, id=3184, stack(0x00000000614b0000,0x00000000615b0000)]
  0x000000005b86e800 JavaThread "Timer-7" [_thread_blocked, id=6928, stack(0x0000000061350000,0x0000000061450000)]
  0x000000005b86d800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5764, stack(0x00000000610e0000,0x00000000611e0000)]
  0x000000005b86d000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:73:1d:c6" [_thread_blocked, id=2936, stack(0x0000000060f60000,0x0000000061060000)]
  0x000000005b86c000 JavaThread "Timer-6" [_thread_blocked, id=2944, stack(0x0000000060160000,0x0000000060260000)]
  0x000000005b86b800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:bf:45:71" [_thread_blocked, id=2808, stack(0x0000000060d00000,0x0000000060e00000)]
  0x000000005b86a800 JavaThread "Timer-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5116, stack(0x0000000060580000,0x0000000060680000)]
  0x000000005b86a000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1136, stack(0x0000000060bc0000,0x0000000060cc0000)]
  0x000000005b869000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:8e:5e:3f" [_thread_blocked, id=4076, stack(0x00000000609f0000,0x0000000060af0000)]
  0x000000005c524800 JavaThread "Timer-4" [_thread_blocked, id=4004, stack(0x0000000060810000,0x0000000060910000)]
  0x000000005c524000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=6828, stack(0x0000000060680000,0x0000000060780000)]
  0x000000005c523000 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=1356, stack(0x00000000603b0000,0x00000000604b0000)]
  0x000000005c522800 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:c8:a9:c0" [_thread_blocked, id=5628, stack(0x0000000060260000,0x0000000060360000)]
  0x000000005c521800 JavaThread "Timer-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1428, stack(0x000000005f830000,0x000000005f930000)]
  0x000000005c521000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:cb:f5:59" [_thread_blocked, id=5036, stack(0x0000000060060000,0x0000000060160000)]
  0x000000005c520000 JavaThread "Timer-2" [_thread_blocked, id=6024, stack(0x000000005ff50000,0x0000000060050000)]
  0x000000005c51f800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=5588, stack(0x000000005fa80000,0x000000005fb80000)]
  0x000000005c51e800 JavaThread "socketRcvDataProcess" [_thread_in_native, id=6124, stack(0x000000005fd50000,0x000000005fe50000)]
  0x000000005c51e000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:fa:6a:54" [_thread_blocked, id=5832, stack(0x000000005fb80000,0x000000005fc80000)]
  0x000000005c771000 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4556, stack(0x000000005f970000,0x000000005fa70000)]
  0x000000005c603000 JavaThread "profile.08:00:27:49:bc:29" [_thread_blocked, id=5788, stack(0x000000005d130000,0x000000005d230000)]
  0x000000005c601800 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5408, stack(0x000000005f2a0000,0x000000005f3a0000)]
  0x000000005c229800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5844, stack(0x0000000059e60000,0x0000000059f60000)]
  0x000000005b004800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=3104, stack(0x0000000059070000,0x0000000059170000)]
  0x000000005c342800 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3124, stack(0x000000005cc10000,0x000000005cd10000)]
  0x000000000034d800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2256, stack(0x0000000001fa0000,0x00000000020a0000)]
  0x0000000058cee000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4048, stack(0x000000005aae0000,0x000000005abe0000)]
  0x00000000592c8800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4208, stack(0x0000000059f80000,0x000000005a080000)]
  0x00000000592c7800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5244, stack(0x0000000059d40000,0x0000000059e40000)]
  0x00000000592c7000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3112, stack(0x0000000059bb0000,0x0000000059cb0000)]
  0x0000000058970800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2540, stack(0x0000000059180000,0x0000000059280000)]
  0x00000000588f9000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3236, stack(0x0000000058f60000,0x0000000059060000)]
=>0x00000000588f2000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3728, stack(0x0000000058d20000,0x0000000058e20000)]
  0x0000000056f55000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4580, stack(0x00000000587f0000,0x00000000588f0000)]
  0x0000000056f53000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3284, stack(0x0000000058610000,0x0000000058710000)]
  0x0000000056f50000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6348, stack(0x0000000058420000,0x0000000058520000)]
  0x0000000056f39800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4160, stack(0x0000000058310000,0x0000000058410000)]
  0x0000000056ef2800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5148, stack(0x00000000581d0000,0x00000000582d0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000056eea800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000057fc0000,0x00000000580c0000] [id=4120]
  0x000000005899e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000058e60000,0x0000000058f60000] [id=1204]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000000000034bba0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000005b004800

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 230912K, used 31976K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000e5100000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 230400K, 13% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d823a250,0x00000000e4400000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x00000000e4400000,0x00000000e4400000,0x00000000e4480000)
  to   space 6656K, 0% used [0x00000000e4a80000,0x00000000e4a80000,0x00000000e5100000)
 ParOldGen       total 125440K, used 38956K [0x0000000082800000, 0x000000008a280000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 125440K, 31% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000084e0b3d0,0x000000008a280000)
 Metaspace       used 19249K, capacity 19508K, committed 19968K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2138K, capacity 2252K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011730000,0x0000000011b20000] byte_map_base: 0x000000001131c000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006e38a6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000122b0000, 0x0000000014210000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014210000, 0x0000000016170000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000300000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=21546Kb max_used=21598Kb free=224213Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002370000, 0x00000000038b0000, 0x0000000011370000]
 total_blobs=5173 nmethods=4603 adapters=480
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 29.470 Thread 0x00000000588f9000 5877   !   3       java.awt.Container::isParentOf (49 bytes)
Event: 29.471 Thread 0x00000000588f9000 nmethod 5877 0x0000000002a03d90 code [0x0000000002a03f20, 0x0000000002a04608]
Event: 29.473 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 nmethod 5875 0x0000000002e07690 code [0x0000000002e07820, 0x0000000002e07ca8]
Event: 29.474 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 5878  s    4       sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage::getHeight (48 bytes)
Event: 29.475 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 nmethod 5878 0x0000000002f1aa90 code [0x0000000002f1abe0, 0x0000000002f1ae58]
Event: 29.475 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 5876       4       java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter::setHints (24 bytes)
Event: 29.476 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 nmethod 5876 0x0000000003894b90 code [0x0000000003894ce0, 0x0000000003894e08]
Event: 29.481 Thread 0x00000000588f9000 5879   !   3       java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager::getFocusOwner (42 bytes)
Event: 29.482 Thread 0x00000000588f9000 nmethod 5879 0x000000000388ad10 code [0x000000000388aea0, 0x000000000388b2e8]
Event: 29.482 Thread 0x00000000588f2000 5880   !   4       sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource::doFetch (253 bytes)
```

Posting another part of error log

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: cant post full error log... please help me how to post

Answer (score 1):

This is not the application log. This is an error of JRE itself. This also explains why it was working previously and why it's working on another PC.

There is not much you can do about it except for installing a different version of Java Runtime.